# Exclusions in DiscretePlot and DiscretePlot3D

Tags: plotting

How do I exclude certain values from a `DiscretePlot` or a `DiscretePlot3D`?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ListPlot` if values had to be excluded

```
DiscretePlot[Tan[x], {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
tab = Table[Tan[x], {x, -2, 2, 0.1}];

ListPlot[tab, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> Automatic, DataRange -> {-2, 2}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[tab /. x_ /; Abs[x] > 10 :> Null, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {-2, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the excluded points/regions from the function domain using `ConditionalExpression` or using `RegionFunction`:

```
exclusions = Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/3];
p2d = Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
plt1 = Show[DiscretePlot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full], p2d, 
        ImageSize -> 300];
plt2 = Show[DiscretePlot[ConditionalExpression[Sin[t], Not[MemberQ[exclusions, t]]], 
        {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full], p2d, ImageSize -> 300];
plt3 = Show[DiscretePlot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full,
          RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Not[MemberQ[exclusions, x]]]], p2d,  
       ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{plt1, plt2, plt3}]
```

[image]

```
plt2a = Show[DiscretePlot[ConditionalExpression[Sin[t], Not[2 <= t < 4]],
    {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize->Full], p2d,  ImageSize -> 300];
plt3a = Show[DiscretePlot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full,
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Not[2 <= x < 4]]], p2d, ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{plt1, plt2a, plt3a}]
```

[image]

```
p3d = Plot3D[PDF[BinormalDistribution[0.5], {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.4], Yellow], Mesh -> None];

exclusions2 = RandomSample[Range[-2, 2, 2/10], 6];

plt1b = Show[p3d, DiscretePlot3D[PDF[BinormalDistribution[0.5], {x, y}], 
    {x, -2, 2, 2/10}, {y, -2, 2, 2/10}, ExtentSize -> Full], 
    ImageSize -> 300,  ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 2 Pi}];

plt2b = Show[p3d, DiscretePlot3D[ConditionalExpression[
     PDF[BinormalDistribution[0.5], {x, y}], Not[MemberQ[exclusions2, x | y]]], 
    {x, -2, 2, 2/10}, {y, -2, 2, 2/10}, ExtentSize -> Full], 
    ImageSize -> 300, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 2 Pi}];

plt3b = Show[p3d, DiscretePlot3D[PDF[BinormalDistribution[0.5], {x, y}],
    {x, -2, 2, 2/10}, {y, -2, 2, 2/10}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Not[MemberQ[exclusions2, x | y]]]], 
   ImageSize -> 300, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 2 Pi}];

   Row[{plt1b, plt2b, plt3b}]
```

[image]

```
plt2c = Show[p3d, DiscretePlot3D[ConditionalExpression[
  PDF[BinormalDistribution[0.5], {x, y}], 
  Not[2 <= x ^2 + y^2 <= 3]], {x, -2, 2, 2/10}, {y, -2, 2, 2/10}, 
  ExtentSize -> Full], ImageSize -> 300, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 2 Pi}];

plt3c = Show[p3d, DiscretePlot3D[PDF[BinormalDistribution[0.5], {x, y}], 
  {x, -2, 2, 2/10}, {y, -2, 2, 2/10}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Not[2 <= x ^2 + y^2 <= 3]]],
  ImageSize -> 300, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 2 Pi}];

 Row[{plt1b, plt2c, plt3c}]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with `ConditionalExpression` is that it evaluates the argument, so singular points (that I want to avoid) will generate messages or give errors. The same occurs with `RegionFunction`. Is there a way to prevent the function from being evaluated at excluded points?

Comment: @becko, can you give a small example?

Comment: `DiscretePlot[1/x, {x, -10, 10}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x < -2 \[Or] x > 2]]`

Comment: @becko, can't think of any fix except using `Quiet` to suppress the message.